# Android json result null

Tags: android, json

hello everyone i try to parse json .i have simple json like this[like this](http://postimg.org/image/igbwlkoo5/)

i try to parse this json but result is null .i have no idea what i'm doing wrong
this is a my code

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
private String URL = "*****************";
private TextView PNumber;

JSONArray jsonArray = null;

public static String KEY_PNumber = "PNumber";
String id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    PNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PNumber);
    new LoadDataAllChanelsToServer().execute();
}

private class LoadDataAllChanelsToServer extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();


        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);

         try {

    JSONObject jsonObject = json.getJSONObject("data");

    id = jsonObject.getString("PNumber");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        PNumber.setText(id);
    }

}
```

}

what am i doing wrong if anyone knows solution help me  thanks

i have this errror
error occurred while executing doinbackground()

Answer (score 1):

The Json you posted does not contain any array. Its a JSON object. A Json array starts with `[`. You can read more about JSON from [here](http://www.json.org/).

Now, regarding parsing:

Do it as follows:

```
    try {

        JSONObject jsonObject = json.getJSONObject("data");

        String pNumber = jsonObject.getString("PNumber");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i changed it but nothing happened

Comment: Have you checked the logcat?Just make sure no JSONException has occured during parsing.

Comment: And try to print the response you got from server

Comment: at the moment i have this error  ----android asynctask error occurred while executing doinbackground()  what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Post your full logcat stack